# second derivative of a parametric equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

can someone please explain how in the proof for the second differential of a parametric function we get from [image] to [image]?

how do we calculate $\frac {d}{dt}$?

Comment: this is the quotient rule

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner 
 
Can you also apply (d/dt) on 1/(dx/dt) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the quotient rule, which states generally:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=\frac{g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{[g(x)]^{2}}$$

Applying this to your formula we have:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}\right)\frac{1}{\dot{x}}=\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\left[\frac{\dot{x}\ddot{y}-\dot{y}\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}^{2}}\right]=\frac{\dot{x}\ddot{y}-\dot{y}\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}^{3}}$$

As required.

---

We can also do this using the product rule:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right)=f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$

We therefore have:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\dot{y} \frac{1}{\dot{x}}\right)\frac{1}{\dot{x}}=\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\left[\frac{\ddot{y}}{\dot{x}}-\frac{\dot{y}\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}^{2}}\right]=\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\left[\frac{\dot{x}\ddot{y}-\dot{y}\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}^{2}}\right]=\frac{\dot{x}\ddot{y} - \dot{y}\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}^{3}}$$

As required.

Comment: Can you also apply (d/dt) on 1/(dx/dt) instead?

Comment: You can, you could do this via the product rule on $$\dot{y} \frac{1}{\dot{x}}$$ But using the Quotient rule just reduces the number of steps required.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't bring the same results

Comment: @Bak1139 I've updated my answer to show how the product rule can be applied to get the same result.

Comment: youve put much effort, thanks.

Comment: @Bak1139 No problem, glad to help! :)